# Datalogger storage calculation

Tags: data-storage

How to calculate the required storage capacity of a data logger given the measurement time sampling rate and resolution?

I want to log two voltages at 1Hz rate for 3 months continuously  and looking for a cheap data logger for this purpose. But most of them have not enough storage.

Comment: `Data_per_sample x Samples_per_second x seconds_in_total`

Comment: It would make more sense to monitor and save changes and disturbances

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 It is  a bit dangerous. Is some portion of the data is lost - everything (after that point) is lost...

Comment: absolute data can be included less frequently say once an hour or day to permit.. DATAQ makes RMS loggers

Comment: But if you are concerned about PC PSU loss of power, then dropouts > 1 cycle must be detected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really basic math, although you left out one important parameter, which is the sample size.

Let's say each sample is 16 bits for sake of example.  At 1 Hz rate, that means you need 16 bits, or two bytes, for every second of running time.  Your running time is 3 months.  Do the math:

(3 months)(30 days/month)(24 hours/day)(3600 s/hour)(2 bytes/s)(2 channels) = 31 MBytes

Yes, it really is that simple.

Answer (score 3):

Isn't this just basic maths?

1 sample per second * 60 seconds * 60 minutes * 24 hours * 30 days * 3 months = 7,776,000 points.

Assuming a 16 bit ADC that is then 2 channels * 2 bytes * 7,776,000 = 31.104 MBytes of data.

Even allowing for basic checksums and data formatting any data logger with the ability to log to an SD card should do the job.

Comment: Not even maths...arithmetic. Upvoted.

Comment: Actually, it's basic *math*, not *maths*, but still otherwise correct.  "Math" is a subject of study, so the plural form doesn't make any sense.  You don't say "physicses", "geologies", or "arithmetics" either.

Comment: @OlinLathrop ... http://grammarist.com/spelling/math-maths/

Comment: don't forget the timestamp...